# Unable to trigger jQuery verification plugin on click

Tags: jquery, validation

I'm unable to get my form validation below to respond unless I enter text and tab to the next one. Clicking a different field or hitting submit does nothing, and I'd want it to respond in all scenarios. Honestly this is the first time I've used jquery for anything more complex than enabling or disabling classes, so I'm probably making a basic error somewhere. I can't figure out what it is however.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.9/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    //form validation 
   $(document).ready(function() {
       $("#form").validate({
            rules: {
                organization: {
                    required: true,
                    minlength: 2,
                    },
                firstname: {
                    required: true,
                    minlength: 2,
                    },
                lastname: {
                    required: true,
                    minlength: 2,
                    },
                email: {
                    required: true,
                    email: true,
                    },
                phone: {
                    required: true,
                    minlength: 10,
                    number: true,
                    },
            },
            messages: {
                organization: "Please enter a valid organization name",
                firstname: "Please enter your first name",
                lastname: "Please enter your last name",
                email: "Please enter a valid email address",
                phone: "Please enter a valid phone number",
            },
        });         
   });
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="form_container">
    <div id="form_title">REQUEST INFO</div>
    <form id="form" name="form_container" action="#">
        <!-- fields -->
        <input id="organization" type="text" name="organization" minlength="2" />
        <input id="firstname" type="text" name="firstname" minlength="2" />
        <input id="lastname" type="text"  name="lastname" minlength="2" />
        <input id="email" type="text" name="email" />
        <input id="phone" type="text" name="phone" />
        <!-- submit button -->
        <input type="button" id="button" name="submit" type="submit" value="submit" > 
    </form>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have 2 type attributes on your submit button

```
<input type="button" id="button" name="submit" type="submit" value="submit" >
```

Change it to this

```
<input id="button" name="submit" type="submit" value="submit" />
```

This will cause the button to submit the form, and trigger the validation plugin in the way you expect. Also, your validation configuration object has some extra trailing commas in a few places (after the the last field of each subobject) that may trip up some older browsers (IE in particular).

Comment: Wow. Thank you for pointing that out! In my focus on the jquery I completely forgot to double-check my html attributes. Also thanks for the tip about the commas.

Comment: Done. Sorry... first time actually asking on stackoverflow.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the `.focusin()` and `.focusout()` jQuery event methods. The other thing you might want to look at is the `.submit()` method, if you intend to do more validation when the visitor clicks the "submit" button, before you actually perform the submission.

Let me know if you need any more guidance or further explanation/examples. Good Luck! :)

Comment: Thank you! That points me in the right direction for future interations

Comment: Always happy to help. Upgrade it if you think that it will be helpful to others :)